# Can I use pattern matching in C program?

Tags: c, linux, string

I am novice to C programming. Is it possible to match pattern inside the C string, like any built in functions?

I am using Red Hat Linux and I want to check if a string starts with `abc:` or `def:` followed by 10 digit numbers `@` chars. Something like : `(abc|def):([0-9]{10})@([A-Za-z0-9]*)`.

Is there any C built in function which I can use to check this pattern matching.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use POSIX regex matching in linux. See man 3 regex for more details.
If you are looking for a fast, safe and threaded library you can use re2 library from Google with support like pre-compiled regex.
(https://github.com/google/re2)

Answer (score 0):

Linux and POSIX have [regex(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regex.3.html) functions. You'll need to "compile" -that is prepare by transforming- your regular expression string using `regcomp` first.

In some simple cases, you might also use other string functions, like `strstr`, `strchr`, [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) (the `%n` format specifier might be handy, to know how much bytes you have scanned).

You could also consider some [lexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) utility, perhaps using [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/) to generate a tokenizer able to recognize your regexp.